# Unable to boot windows safe mode. Windows 10 pro

Tags: windows-10, reboot

I was trying to get windows to boot into safe mode.

I changed settings to boot into safe mode using msconfig.
Changes made:
Msconfig > Boot tab > tick boot windows in safe mode.
I followed these instructions:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode

Now it would not boot into windows at all.

Screen show a black screen but monitor is not turned off. It does not even load to the part where I can go into bios menu.

What can I do?

Comment: "I changed settings to boot into safe mode using msconfig." - What changes?  It sounds like the changes you made now prevent you from booting into Windows entirely?  Edit your question to clarify that point if that is the case.

Comment: I've added the changes made. Basically I just enabled windows to boot into safe mode by ticking the option to go to safe mode then I restarted the PC.

Comment: If Windows fails to boot three times, it's supposed to boot into the Advanced Startup, if that isn't happening you might have a bigger problem.  Also are you sure the problem isn't with your display configuration, and Windows actually is booting, but due to the displays not being detected you are not aware of that fact?

Comment: I encountered this same problem when I tried entering safe mode this way. "Use "Shift + Restart" on the Windows 10 Sign In screen". After which, I boot windows the normal way (not safe mode), and it managed to boot. Sorry I am not sure whether this eliminates the issue of "display not being detected".

Comment: Malware is known to affect settings that can prevent windows from booting in safe mode. Why are you trying to boot in to safe mode?

Comment: I was trying to switch to a different antivirus software. From AVG to Kaspersky. Thus, I was trying to uninstall AVG completely, and had troubles uninstalling AVG completely, so I entered safe mode so that I can use AVG remover to remove the software completely.